# collapse blocks of code in spyder - works sometimes but not others

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Using anaconda and spyder v4.0.1 here...

I have an issue with collapsing blocks of code - classes, functions, if statements, etc.

Sometimes I have the option to collapse, sometimes I don't??

For example..I'm working on a script in the editor called `script.py`.

I wanted to make another version to try some different approaches in some functions, called it `script1.py`.

When I open `script1.py`, there are no "arrows" to let me collapse the code blocks. In `script.py` they are there.

I tried re-opening the script and then it worked. Then I saved the script after some changes and now the arrows are gone. I restarted my computer and then it worked again. Then I closed and opened the script and it stopped working again.

This is really annoying...is this a bug? Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: It's a new roll out, probably lots of bugs and stuff. I don't like their autocomplete, jumps up in the middle of typing a lot. Takes a few patches before it's stable.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Folding regions are recomputed every time a change is made. And sometimes the server we use in the background to do that fails for reasons we're still trying to understand. Are your scripts very long (i.e. thousands of lines of code)?

Comment: @anishtain4 might be mistaken but I think you can change how long it takes for autocomplete to pop up while typing?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Was hoping to hear from you XD seen you on alot of questions...thanks for the input...they are not long, in the order of 100-500 lines-ish..also, sometimes when Iadd some empty lines above a function by pressing enter, the function gets bumped down but the arrows stay at the same line number they were at before and collapse a random block of code

Comment: "Sometimes when I add some empty lines above a function by pressing enter, the function gets bumped down but the arrows stay at the same line number they were at before and collapse a random block of code". This problem was reported before and we're looking at fixing it.

Comment: In my experience, it allows code folding for large codes. I read somewhere that it is enabled for codes with > 300 lines for version 4.1.5.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `#%%` to separate blocks of the code. The arrow on the left of the pane can then be used to minimize the blocks of the code.

Comment: Sorry, what arrow? It works to separate code, but I'm still unable to minimize it

Comment: Before the chunk of the code you want to minimize, add a line `#%%`. Do the same after the chunk of the code. Now if you hover to the left of the first `#%%`, you can see a small triangle, which can be used to minimize the desired chunk. Hope this works!

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Spyder3. it seems the option is available from Spyder5. Am I right?

Comment: I know this is available in Spyder5. I'm not sure from which version it started being available.